# SVG - проблемы с анимацией

Tags: javascript, html, svg, анимация, smil

У меня есть некоторые фигуры, которые я вращаю, используя две кнопки,- одну для вращения по часовой стрелке, а другую против  часовой стрелки:

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function cwAnim(evt) {
  if (window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  addRotateTransform('someShape', 1, -1, 180);
  addRotateTransform('shape1', 1, 1, 360);
  addRotateTransform('shape2', 1, 1, 360);
}

function acwAnim(evt) {
  if (window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  addRotateTransform('someShape', 1, 1, 180);
  addRotateTransform('shape1', 1, -1, 360);
  addRotateTransform('shape2', 1, -1, 360);
}

function addRotateTransform(target_id, dur, dir, angle) {
  var my_element = svgDoc.getElementById(target_id);
  var a = svgDoc.createElementNS(svgNS, "animateTransform");

  var bb = my_element.getBBox();
  var cx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
  var cy = bb.y + bb.height / 2;

  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeName", "transform");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeType", "XML");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "type", "rotate");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", dur + "s");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "repeatCount", "1");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "freeze");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "additive", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "accumulate", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "from", "0 " + cx + " " + cy);
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "to", angle * dir + " " + cx + " " + cy);

  my_element.appendChild(a);
  a.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <circle stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="468.451" cy="474.385" r="350" />
  <g id="someShape">
    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="468.451" cy="474.385" r="350" />
    <path id="shape1" fill="#DC5A00" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M692.373,317.798C692.373,418.425,606.244,500,500,500
   c-106.245,0-192.374-81.575-192.374-182.202c0-100.629,86.128-182.204,192.374-182.204
   C606.244,135.595,692.373,217.169,692.373,317.798z M553.391,220.34c-39.316,0-71.188,31.87-71.188,71.187
   s31.871,71.187,71.188,71.187c39.314,0,71.186-31.87,71.186-71.187S592.705,220.34,553.391,220.34z" />
    <path id="shape2" fill="#3DFF63" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M577.368,647.034c0,69.738-56.913,126.271-127.119,126.271
   c-70.206,0-127.119-56.533-127.119-126.271c0-69.737,56.913-126.271,127.119-126.271
   C520.455,520.764,577.368,577.297,577.368,647.034z M466.352,617.373c-21.998,0-39.831,17.453-39.831,38.983
   c0,21.529,17.833,38.982,39.831,38.982s39.831-17.453,39.831-38.982C506.182,634.826,488.349,617.373,466.352,617.373z" />
  </g>
  <g onclick="cwAnim(evt)">
    <rect x="89.762" y="815.369" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="217.865" height="134.426" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 127.4673 864.5491)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="21">AntiClockwise</text>
  </g>
  <g onclick="acwAnim(evt)">
    <rect x="692.373" y="815.369" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="194.11" height="134.426" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 752.0576 869.467)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="21">Clockwise</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку один раз, анимация срабатывает хорошо.
Проблема возникает, когда я быстро нажимаю несколько раз на кнопки (двойной щелчок, тройной щелчок и т.д).
Ось вращения смещается, и это, конечно, нежелательно.

Есть ли способ решить эту проблему?
 Что-то вроде, когда я нажимаю на другую кнопку, предыдущая анимация останавливается  с сохранение позиции, и происходит новая анимация.

Источник: [SVG - Animation Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31454203/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/31454203/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Добавив переменную `busy`, вы можете указать, что  в настоящее время текущая  анимация занята, и  не нужно начинать новую анимацию. Вы можете сделать больше с этим, но это уже исправляет основную проблему.

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var busy = false;

function animationDelegate(evt, direction){
    /* Проверка состояния переменной,  прежде чем делать, что-либо */
    /* Если анимация активна, то прекратить выполнение  запроса на выполнение новой анимации */
    if(busy) return; else busy = true;
    if(direction === 'cw') cwAnim(evt);
    else if(direction === 'ccw') acwAnim(evt);
    /* Продолжительность анимации 1s. или по другому 1000ms.*/
    /* Set a timeout that resets busy.*/
    setTimeout(function(){ busy = false}, 1000);
}

function cwAnim(evt){
  if ( window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  addRotateTransform('someShape', 1, -1, 180);
  addRotateTransform('shape1', 1, 1, 360);
  addRotateTransform('shape2', 1, 1, 360);    
}

function acwAnim(evt){
  if ( window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  addRotateTransform('someShape', 1, 1, 180);
  addRotateTransform('shape1', 1, -1, 360);
  addRotateTransform('shape2', 1, -1, 360);       
}

function addRotateTransform(target_id, dur, dir, angle){
  var my_element = svgDoc.getElementById(target_id);
  var a = svgDoc.createElementNS(svgNS, "animateTransform");

  var bb = my_element.getBBox();
  var cx = bb.x + bb.width/2;
  var cy = bb.y + bb.height/2;

  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeName", "transform");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeType", "XML");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "type", "rotate");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", dur + "s");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "repeatCount", "1");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "freeze");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "additive", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "accumulate", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "from", "0 "+cx+" "+cy);
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "to", angle*dir+" "+cx+" "+cy);

  my_element.appendChild(a);
  a.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
  <circle stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="468.451" cy="474.385" r="350" />
  <g id="someShape">
    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="468.451" cy="474.385" r="350" />
    <path id="shape1" fill="#DC5A00" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M692.373,317.798C692.373,418.425,606.244,500,500,500
   c-106.245,0-192.374-81.575-192.374-182.202c0-100.629,86.128-182.204,192.374-182.204
   C606.244,135.595,692.373,217.169,692.373,317.798z M553.391,220.34c-39.316,0-71.188,31.87-71.188,71.187
   s31.871,71.187,71.188,71.187c39.314,0,71.186-31.87,71.186-71.187S592.705,220.34,553.391,220.34z" />
    <path id="shape2" fill="#3DFF63" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M577.368,647.034c0,69.738-56.913,126.271-127.119,126.271
   c-70.206,0-127.119-56.533-127.119-126.271c0-69.737,56.913-126.271,127.119-126.271
   C520.455,520.764,577.368,577.297,577.368,647.034z M466.352,617.373c-21.998,0-39.831,17.453-39.831,38.983
   c0,21.529,17.833,38.982,39.831,38.982s39.831-17.453,39.831-38.982C506.182,634.826,488.349,617.373,466.352,617.373z" />
  </g>
  <g onclick="animationDelegate(evt, 'ccw')">
    <rect x="89.762" y="815.369" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="217.865" height="134.426" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 127.4673 864.5491)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="21">AntiClockwise</text>
  </g>
  <g onclick="animationDelegate(evt, 'cw')">
    <rect x="692.373" y="815.369" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="194.11" height="134.426" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 752.0576 869.467)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="21">Clockwise</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Источник: [SVG - Animation Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31455497/7394871)  @somethinghere